# JavaScript Make the second dropdown value equal the hidden dropdown value when selected

Tags: javascript

I have a repeated dropdown hidden list (tfa_1043) in FormAssembly and when a value is changed I need the displayed dropdown list (tfa_4) option value selection to equal tfa_1043 selection

```
  function getSelectedValue(){    
  var x = document.getElementById("tfa_43").selectedIndex;
  var y = document.getElementById("tfa_43").options;

  //change the index number of each dropdown to match event dropdown index
  document.getElementById("tfa_1043").selectedIndex = y[x].index;//HIDEN-LOCATION

  var z = document.getElementById("tfa_1043")
  var i = z.selectedIndex;
  document.getElementById("tfa_4").options.value = z.options[i].text;//DISPLAYED LOCATION
   return;


}  

// 

);
```

Comment: what is the context of this code. Lightning, VF, vf component, lightning component?

Comment: I'm using a form builder called FormAssemmbly that is connected/integrated to Sales Cloud. The form allows me to add JavaScript and I'm trying to manipulate a dropdownlist based on a mapped picklist from SF to the form.

Comment: Robert, welcome to SFSE! I want to encourage you read our [Ask] page. On that note, I'd like to point out that your question is really a javascript question, not really a salesforce one. Because of that, I'd like to suggest you hit the "Stack Overflow" forum where you'll likely get a lot of better answers. If your question does have a relation to the salesforce plaftorm, I encourage you to edit your question with more detail, showing how salesforce-specific components or pages are affected

Comment: We wouldn't normally address non-Salesforce-related questions in this form, but we use FormAssembly where I work.  I'll see if any of my coworkers can point you in the right direction.

Comment: @Himanshu -- it's Javascript used inside a product called FormAssembly, which, without any code in theory, lets you buid dynamic webforms that interface with Salesforce, among other systems.  Obviously the, "without code," part isn't always true!

Comment: @RobertWynter -- a suggestion: You may want to name your variables in a way that makes it simpler to keep track of what's going on, especially in the confusing world of FormAssembly!  For instance: "index" instead of "x"; "options" instead of "y", etc.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that each of the drop downs tfa_43, tfa_1043, and tfa_4 have the same options set for them. Then it seems like you just need to set the selectedIndex for each equal to x.

```
function getSelectedValue(){    
    var x = document.getElementById("tfa_43").selectedIndex;

    //change the index number of each dropdown to match event dropdown index
    document.getElementById("tfa_1043").selectedIndex = x;  //HIDEN-LOCATION

    document.getElementById("tfa_4").selectedIndex = x;   //DISPLAYED LOCATION
    return;
}
```